# Printing out array of hash in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, printing

So I have the following code:

```
while (my $line = <$data>){
   my $fields = split /,/, $line;
   my $name = fields[0];
   my $nickname = fields[1];
   my $occurences = fields[2];
   my $number = fields[3];

   # I need to push it like this so that $occurences are in numerical order, i.e: 0,1,2,....,10
   push @{$hash{$name}{$nickname}}, {$occurences=>$number};  
}

for my $name (keys %hash) {
  for my $nickname (keys %{$hash{$name}}) {
    for my $value (keys @{$hash{$name}{$nickname}}) {
      print "Value is Occurences: $value\n";
    }
  }
}
```

So I can print out the $occurences by doing that thing above but how do I print out the $number? I can't seem to figure out how to print $number.

Input data:

```
Name,Nickname,Occurences,Number
BobWill,bob,1,10
BobWill,bob,1,9
BobWill,bob,1,2
BobWill,bob,2,3
BobWill,bob,6,5
BobWill,bob,3,7
BobWill,will,1,10
BobWill,will,1,9
BobWill,will,1,2
BobWill,will,2,3
BobWill,will,3,5
BobWill,will,3,7
Danny,dan,10,2
Danny,dan,1,3
Danny,dan,8,9
```

Output Expected:

```
Value is Occurences: 1
 Number is: 10
Value is Occurences: 1
 Number is: 9
Value is Occurences: 1
 Number is: 2
Value is Occurences: 2
 Number is: 3
 .
 .
 .
```

"Value is Occurences: #", The # should be in increasing order.

Comment: What about using sample data with `__DATA__` ? https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

Comment: Why are you trying to use `keys` on an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps following code demonstrates how desired result can be achieved

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @fields = split ',', <DATA>;
my %hash;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my($name,$nickname,$occurence,$number) = split ',';
    push @{$hash{$name}{$nickname}{$occurence}},$number;
}

for my $name (keys %hash) {
  for my $nickname (keys %{$hash{$name}}) {
    for my $occurence (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$hash{$name}{$nickname}}) {
      say "$name:$nickname:$occurence:"
        . join(',',sort {$a <=> $b} @{$hash{$name}{$nickname}{$occurence}});
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
Name,Nickname,Occurences,Number
BobWill,bob,1,10
BobWill,bob,1,9
BobWill,bob,1,2
BobWill,bob,2,3
BobWill,bob,6,5
BobWill,bob,3,7
BobWill,will,1,10
BobWill,will,1,9
BobWill,will,1,2
BobWill,will,2,3
BobWill,will,3,5
BobWill,will,3,7
Danny,dan,10,2
Danny,dan,1,3
Danny,dan,8,9
```

Produced output

```
BobWill:will:1:2,9,10
BobWill:will:2:3
BobWill:will:3:5,7
BobWill:bob:1:2,9,10
BobWill:bob:2:3
BobWill:bob:3:7
BobWill:bob:6:5
Danny:dan:1:3
Danny:dan:8:9
Danny:dan:10:2
```